# mod_rewrite ignore "fake" folder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm currently trying to rewrite urls using mod_rewrite..

i was using codeigniters standard *.htaccess* to remove the index.php from my urls:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

urls look like this:

> app.url.com/controller/function/param

i'm trying to add new folder to my url structure (for tenant ids) in the urls:

> app.url.com/**tenantid**/controller/function/param

i want to read that "folder" later by php but i dont want it to affect the rewriting.

i think this should've worked:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /index.php/$2 [L]
```

But unfortunately this results in a 404-error.

Does anyone have a clue whats wrong with the above statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading slash in your pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /index.php/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!
Now i'm arriving at a codeigniter 404. I just tried to output the $_GET-array to see what is handled by php. But the array is empty?

Comment: That's logic because you don't pass any `GET` param to your `index.php`

Comment: Hm. According to http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html i thought the rewrited url /class/function/ID would be handled as a get parameter after the rewriting.

applying ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /index.php/$2 results in a working call for /class/function/ID but not for tenantid/class/function/ID - I suppose, the tenantid still gets passed to the index.php function handling the routing?

Comment: This is only an internal controller/dispatcher which is handling url requested. With the rule i posted in my answer (almost same as yours) it should work and `tenantid` should not be passed to `index.php`

Comment: Yep, i was the same opinion. Applying the pattern you mentioned works when i call url.com/auth/login but leads to a codeigniter 404 with url.com/somevalue/auth/login. Strangely the behaviour is extactly the same with your rule, rewriting to $1 instead of $2

Comment: What represents `tenantid` ? Only numbers ? If yes, how many digit ?

Comment: tenantid -> any character, except slash to find the real CI parameters.
Tested it with an alternative index.php. The rewriting obviously works, looks like a problem on the CI site...

Thanks for your help!